# Ali Express and credit card frauds?

Tags: credit-card, fraud

A lot of people around me claims that they have been victims of credit card thefts after shopping on Ali Express (one person even claims it happened several times). I am very sceptical to this because AE have hundreds of millions of customers and if someone at AE was stealing CC-numbers, it should be millions of victims and a big scandal.

Googling for it returns a lot of results such as

https://www.al6400.com/blog/thinking-aliexpress-caused-my-credit-card-to-be-stolen/

https://www.quora.com/Is-it-safe-to-use-debit-credit-card-on-Aliexpress

https://www.reddit.com/r/Aliexpress/comments/6p5tjo/how_safe_is_credit_card_info_on_ae/

where people claim that their CC details were stolen at AE, but they never substantiate their claims. To me, it sounds like an urban myth and it is much more likely that it happened at a local gas station or taxi or something mundane like that.

Are there any official reports that support/refute that AE has a problem with CC frauds? Or that it ever happened (yes, I know you can't prove non-existence)?

Comment: This doesn't answer your question, but if you happen to have a bank that offers virtual credit cards, you don't have to worry about purchasing from a specific vendor...

Comment: @TTT I am completely unworried. I have disputed a couple of transactions and it has always been a simple and quick process.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that the number of credit cards *stolen* would somehow -by necessity - be proportional to the number of credit cards *available.*  Granted, greed can be a powerful motivator, but if there's only a few bad actors, I don't see any reason why they couldn't restrain themselves to a small number of cards that flies under the radar of statistical anomaly.

Answer (score -1):

Thousands of first-time buyers/sellers are duped by the trick of low prices and positive responses to all questions. Don't be one of those people who think they're smarter than everyone else - until they realize they've only gotten what they paid for.

The issue is not with Alibaba. Some people use the platform to defraud people out of their money. If you follow these tips https://www.hdfcbank.com/personal/resources/learning-centre/pay/smart-tips-to-avoid-credit-card-frauds (found this helpful thread), there is no reason why Alibaba cannot be a safe place to find a profitable product to sell.

Good Luck!!!